# limit UITableView size

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm fetching two kinds of objects in Core Data, some girls and some boys. Each having a size and a born date.

I want to select a maximum of 50 human being, and never more than 10 girls. 
For instance, if I have 15 girls and 5 boys in my database, I want the tableView to print the 5 boys, and the 10 girls (sorting them with their birthdate).

I differentiate boys from girls with a boolean : sexe.

Do you know what is the best way to do this ?

I can limit the total amount here :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[myFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] > 50) {
        return 50;
    } else
    {
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
}
```

but I'm unable to limit the amount of girls in my UITableView.

Thanks, Niels

Comment: What info do you use to know if its a boy or girl. We may be able to come up with a condition only if we know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting (and I won't comment on the sexism).

Don't see any way to write a predicate to limit one half of a search. Assuming the database doesn't change much during the presentation of the table, one technique might be to pre-select the ten girls first, marking them with a transient property includeGirl, then look for a compound predicate of Boy OR includeGirl with a

```
[myBoysFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchLimit:50];
```

Comment: What about creating my own array of NSManagedObject from the NSFetchResultController in the numberOfRowInSection delegate method, and using this new array as my  datasource ?

PS : no sexism at all, you can limit the number of boys if you prefer :)

Comment: Sure, maybe just load the first 60 items into a mutable array, then delete any excess girls.

Comment: Oh, personally, I'd put the array creation in the NSfetch lookup, which is presumably called at viewDidLoad time. Don't forget to reload the array if the NSFetchResultController reports changes to the underlying table.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @mackworth, the table worked well. Then I have done something slightly different, but with the same idea. I created a new core data table, which is updated when changes occur. This table, named Table_Home, has nothing but a 1 to 1 relationship (to a human being). Then, when I ad/remove boys/girls, I update my table as I wish, and my fetch request is executed on the new table. It is better if I want to change the selection algorithm between boys and girls.

Answer (score 0):

At top of my head i can think of creating a datasource after you read from coredata. 
Add objects to data source by using this pseudo code logic. It should be pretty simple to replace it with your program variables.

```
int num_of_girls = 0;
for(i=0;i<50 && data!=nil;i++)
{
    // Fetch object from core data at index i
    if(data==girl && num_of_girls <15)
    {
        // Add to data source the data pertaining to girl
        num_of_girls++;
        i++;
        continue
    }
    // Add to data source as this is pertaining to boy
    i++;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to directly specify this on the request ?

Comment: You can do it in cellforrowatindexpath by maintaining the same variable and removing objects when you get data pertaining girl. If you ok with removing elements from core data when limit is exceeded then its fine. Otherwise the logic will be very complex especially cos the cells are reused and you will have to compute everytime.

Comment: Is it possible to read my NSFetchedResultController during the numberOfRowInSection, and to remove and reorder as I want to ?

Comment: Yes it should be possible as long as you have the object.